# How to send model attribute to spring controller using Postman

Tags: spring, controller, postman

I want to test my controller using postman but don't know how to send a model attribute using postman.

I tried to send all attributes in row json fornamt and x-www-form-urlencoded in body but it is not working for me, I didn't understand where i'm getting wrong

> My controller class looks like :

```
@RestController
public class DemoController {

    @Autowired
    private DemoService demoService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/userDetail", method = { RequestMethod.GET }, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public String testme(
            ModelMap model,
            @ModelAttribute("inputParameter") InputParameter inputParameter,
            BindingResult result) {
        return demoService.getDetail(inputParameter);
    }
}
```

> Model Class :

```java
public class InputParameter {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String number;
    private String address;
    private String pass;
}
```

Comment: Even if it is permitted, it is not common to use `GET` with a body, consider using `POST` or `PUT`.

Comment: Use of GET method is in requirement so need to do this with GET method only